# image reveals on scroll and cover container image

Tags: css, image, animation, scroll, transition

I'm trying to build an effect like the one in the video: https://streamable.com/y00nkj

On scroll the grey house appears, then scrolling down again a new layer appears (the blue border house that overlay the first grey house) covering the first image div.

I'm working with react, and I'm using react-waypoint to trigger scrolling events.
I tried css mask and many others css tricks too without results

**Sample code:**

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="bg-image-fixed"></div>
    <div class="scolling-image"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution with `clip-path`property and some basic JS:

here a pen: https://codepen.io/ufollettu/pen/xxPJmBM?editors=0111